# Unable to locate package postgresql-client-11 in python v3.9.6 or above base image

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, docker

```
FROM python:3.9.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  postgresql-client-11
```

for Dockerfile above, `docker build` commands works smoothly.

But

```
FROM python:3.9.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  postgresql-client-11
```

`docker build` throws the following error.

```
#5 2.088 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [2592 B]
#5 3.086 Fetched 8545 kB in 3s (3341 kB/s)
#5 3.086 Reading package lists...
#5 3.605 Reading package lists...
#5 4.113 Building dependency tree...
#5 4.251 Reading state information...
#5 4.356 E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-11
```

**Unable to locate package postgresql-client-11 in python v3.9.6 or above base image**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
FROM python:3.9.6-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  postgresql-client-11
```

Looks like the `bullseye` version (by default for python:3.9.6 image) does not have `postgresql-client-11` library,
but the `buster` version have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for cleaner install:

```
FROM python:3.10.4-alpine3.16

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# copy project install deps
# install deps for psycopg build and run pip
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
    gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev libffi-dev


WORKDIR /api
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps
```